# Issue with incompatible train and test data in Weka

Tags: weka

I am trying to run a classifier (J48) on dataset in Weka.  I try to supply the test data and although the no of attributes and respective data types in both training and testing set are the same, I constantly receive the error "Problem Evaluating Classifier: Test and Training Set are Not Compatible". Both datasets don't have any record in common.
This error is independent from the classification technique that I select. It occurs as soon as I try to use testing data.
How can I solve this issue? I have checked many times the datatypes and attribute names. They are the same

Comment: That's odd. Are your datasets ARFF files? If not, consider converting them to ARFF first and make sure you are using the latest version of Weka.

Comment: I tried, to convert to ARFF via Weka and via online converters. The same issue persists. I am using Weka 3.6. When I load the same data to RapidMiner no issue occurs. But I need Weka results. What else can I do?

Comment: Off the top of my head: As a quick workaround: Copy datasets together, then apply the "percentage split " option  such that weka splits at the boundary of training/test data. You need to set checkbox "keep order intact" (or something like that), and you need to try a few times to get the split percentage right (even the commas after the decimal point). ALso check the "related questions" sidebar here on SO.

Comment: Can you convert your datasets to ARFF, open them both in the notepad or similar and copy paste the header (all the lines before @DATA) along with your question?

Comment: @knb Thanks for your advice. I know the option of percentage split, but I need preprocessed training and testing sets in order to make sure that each of them contain the right portion of different records categories

Comment: @Josep, I cannot copy paste the header here because I there are around 300 attributes and here is limitation of characters. I am trying to load to drive the original training and testing files in .csv and .arff. I hope it will help you to guide me for the solution of the problem. I will come back in a while

Comment: Link for testing set in csv: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Ms5GvT1GaaYzZpb0VzSUxERms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Link for training set in csv: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Ms5GvT1GaaZnBHdGpvZms0bkk

Comment: Link for training set in arff: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Ms5GvT1GaaMUo0ZTZVNWlBb1E

Comment: Link for testing set in arff: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Ms5GvT1GaaZGIxUjRPZ2UzMTQ

Comment: The class label will be the nominal attribute STATUS. I would be very grateful if you help me with resolving this issue.

Comment: The ARFF files you uploaded for training and testing are exactly the same (they are called `New Full Training DataSEt.arff`). Please upload/link the proper testing.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. You can find here the link for testing dataset in arff format: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Ms5GvT1GaaUnpFTnBSUmFwX2M/view

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the datasets are in fact NOT compatible :)

If you examine closely the headers of the ARFF files you will notice that lines 236 and 237 doesn't match. In your test dataset you need to add the N/A class for the attribute CPR. Also, Weka uses numeric indexing and the order of the categorical values matter. You should swap the values in line 236.

```
236,237c236,237
< @attribute SPR {PR,NPR}
< @attribute CPR {NPR,PR,N/A}
---
> @attribute SPR {NPR,PR}
> @attribute CPR {PR,NPR}
```

I understand that you had CSV files and made the ARFF from those. The automatic process may not take these things into consideration. Usually you will want to use a file including the training and testing cases to generate the headers and either split it or copy paste the headers onto the files generated from individual CSV files.